# Spark: Manipulation of Multiple RDDs

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Recently I've been working on a project using pyspark and I come across this problem that I don't know how to solve.
Basically the manipulation involves 3 files, each of which looks like below,

File 1: mapping one id set(idset1) to another id set(idset2)

lines look like

```
[000001, 15120001]
[000002, 15120002]
...
```

File 2: mapping ids in idset2 to items contains in each of ids in idset2

lines look like

```
[15120001, 600001]
[15120001, 600002]
[15120002, 601988]
...
```

File3 : a series of numbers correspond to each item in each id

lines look like

```
[600001, 1.11, 1.12, 1.32, 1.42, ..., 1.51]
[600002, 5.12, 5.21, 5.23, 5.21, ..., 5.21]
[601988, 52.1, 52.1, 52.2, 52.4, ..., 52.1]
...
```

What I need to do is to get something like

```
[000001, (1.11+5.12)/2,(1.12+5.21)/2,...,(1.51+5.21)/2]
[000002, 52.1, 52.1, 52.2, 52.4, ..., 52.1]
...
```

i.e. map ids in idset1 to equally weighted average of items in ids of idset2 that corresponding to each id in idset1.

If someone understand what I mean, please help me with this. By the way, ids are not auto incremental , they are pre-assigned. Thanks to all who try to help me in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets start with creating example data. I assume all ids are actually strings but it doesn't really affect further computations.

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([["000001", "15120001"], ["000002", "15120002"]])

rdd2 = sc.parallelize([
    ["15120001", "600001"], ["15120001", "600002"],
    ["15120002", "601988"]
])

rdd3 = sc.parallelize([
    ["600001", 1.11, 1.12, 1.32, 1.42, 1.51],
    ["600002", 5.12, 5.21, 5.23, 5.21, 5.21],
    ["601988", 52.1, 52.1, 52.2, 52.4, 52.1]
])
```

Next lets convert all `RDDs` to `DataFrames`:

```
df1 = rdd1.toDF(("id1", "id2"))
df2 = rdd2.toDF(("id2_", "item_id"))

n_features = len(rdd3.first()) - 1
feature_names = ["x_{0}".format(i) for i in range(n_features)]

df3 = rdd3.toDF(["item_id_"] + feature_names)
```

Join data:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

combined = (df1
    .join(df2, col("id2") == col("id2_"))
    .join(df3, col("item_id") == col("item_id_")))
```

and aggregate:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg

exprs = [avg(x).alias(x) for x in feature_names]
aggregated = combined.groupBy(col("id1")).agg(*exprs)
aggregated.show()

## +------+-----+-----+------------------+-----+----+
## |   id1|  x_0|  x_1|               x_2|  x_3| x_4|
## +------+-----+-----+------------------+-----+----+
## |000001|3.115|3.165|3.2750000000000004|3.315|3.36|
## |000002| 52.1| 52.1|              52.2| 52.4|52.1|
## +------+-----+-----+------------------+-----+----+
```

Aggregated data can be converted back to `RDD` if needed:

```
aggregated.map(tuple).collect()
## [('000001', 3.115, 3.165, 3.2750000000000004, 3.315, 3.36),
##     ('000002', 52.1, 52.1, 52.2, 52.4, 52.1)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This is exactly what I want. However there's another issue that my data is pretty large. The grouped data has over 500 million rows and 6000+ columns and it is now taking forever to aggregate(the executor computing time on the monitor page is growing forever and the tasks are running and not moving forward). Is there any way to boost the performance?

Comment: First thing you can try is to `broadcast` id dataframes (df1, df2) to reduce shuffling. If data columns are small you can assemble sparse vectors and aggregate at this level (you'll need an UDAF or switch to RDD for that). Assembling can be done using a VectorAssembler.